# images is not rendering on webpage while mapping the image from data.js file in react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm creating a website in react.js, where I created a data.js file and I'm mapping the data from data.js file using props in my component I got all the data from the data.js file but the image is not rendering on webpage how do I solve this Error?

this is my Sdata.js file

```
const Sdata =[
{
    dataImage:"/images/service-image1.jpg",
    title:"Hatha",
    des:"Lorem ipsum sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing...",
    span:"Monday 20:00 hs.",
}
]

export default Sdata;
```

Tis is my Service-section

```
import React from "react";
import servicebackground from './images/service-background.jpg';
import Sdata from "./Sdata";

function Servicesetion(){
    return(
        <>
            <div className="service-section">
                <div className="service-background">
                    <img src={servicebackground}/>
                </div>
                <div className="servicewrapper">
                    <div className="service-title">
                        <p className="text-center mx-auto text-uppercase">Meet our
                            yoga classes 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-section d-flex mx-auto justify-content-center">
                        {
                            Sdata.map((val) => {
                                return <div className="cardwrapper">
                                            <div className="service-image1">
                                                <img src={val.dataImage}/>
                                            </div>  
                                            <div className="card-title">
                                                <h2>{val.title}</h2>
                                                <p>{val.des}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <span>{val.span}</span>
                                        </div>
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Servicesetion;

This is my app.js file

    import React from 'react';
    import './App.css';
    import Bannersection from './Banner-section';
    import Servicesetion from './Service-section';
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <>
          <Bannersection></Bannersection>
          <Servicesetion></Servicesetion>
        </>
      );
    }

export default App;
```

This is my file strucher

Help me to solve this error

This is my error

Comment: Did u try specifying a height to the div in which the image is rendered?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the image path in `require()`

```
const Sdata =[
{
    dataImage: require("./images/service-image1.jpg"),
    title:"Hatha",
    des:"Lorem ipsum sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing...",
    span:"Monday 20:00 hs.",
}
]

export default Sdata;
```

Or you can do like this:

```
import Image from "./images/service-image1.jpg"

const Sdata =[
{
    dataImage: Image,
    title:"Hatha",
    des:"Lorem ipsum sit amet, consectetur  adipisicing...",
    span:"Monday 20:00 hs.",
}
]

export default Sdata;
```